# Xamarin iOS background upload task (iOS 7) - DidFinishEventsForBackgroundSession

Tags: ios, file-upload, xamarin.ios, xamarin

From what I understand from the documentation **DidFinishEventsForBackgroundSession** is supposed to be called when the task completes (the transfer completes)

I have a progress bar that updates based on the totalBytesSent / totalBytesExpectedToSend, allowing me to tell when it's supposed to be done.

I've also followed the instructions (in regard to uploads) in the walkthrough from the Xamarin at the following link:

[background transfer walkthrough](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/part_4_ios_backgrounding_walkthroughs/background_transfer_walkthrough/)

I put a breakpoint inside the DidFinishEventsForBackgroundSession and it never seemed to get called.

Edit: What is the proper way to detect completion of tasks (or being notified, when in background, for throwing a notification so the user can know it's done)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was having the same issue until I switched to using **didCompleteWithError**. Reading Apple's documentation suggests didCompleteWithError **tells the delegate that the task finished**. This is what I have been using and working like a charm. You can check the error parameter to see if returned an error or if it's null.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionTaskDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLSessionTaskDelegate/URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to answer the question after I found it. Went the same route as you by using the "didCompleteWithError".

Comment: Yea it's very confusing, calling didCompleteWithError although there's no error.